# Why isn't there a viable alternative to XAMPP in Linux?

Tags: lamp, xampp

As per the title, why isn't there an alternative to XAMPP which completely installs in Linux?
I have tried everyone that I've come across and none yet have completely installed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is on-topic here, thanks!

Comment: Voters, this is answerable, Ubuntu server comes with a lamp stack in tasksel

Answer (score 5):

The default stack on Ubuntu (or any Linux system) is LAMP and it has been for a very long time.

> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)
>
> LAMP is a combination of free, open source software. The acronym LAMP refers to the first letters of Linux (operating system), Apache HTTP Server, MySQL (database software), and PHP, Perl or Python, principal components to build a viable general purpose web server.
>
> The exact combination of software included in a LAMP package may vary, especially with respect to the web scripting software, as Perl or Python are sometimes dropped from the stack. Similar terms exist for essentially the same software suite (AMP) running on other operating systems, such as Microsoft Windows (WAMP), Mac OS (MAMP), Solaris (SAMP), iSeries (iAMP), or OpenBSD (OAMP).

Ubuntu has a special program to install extra sets of software (like LAMP); you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

and then choose from a list of options LAMP:

[image]

The system will install a pre-configured version of LAMP and will also ask for password for MySQL admin. This has worked out of the box for me for years

Besides that: please avoid using XAMP since the LAMP stack in Ubuntu is better tested and hardend.

---

Easiest method installing LAMP is this single command:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

The ^ indicates apt-get needs to install the task lamp-server.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you give **[devilbox](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox)** a try. This is a cross-platform dockerized LAMP stack which offers:

- Apache/Nginx
- PHP/HHVM
- MySQL/MariaDB
- PostgreSQL

Additionally you can combine every major version of the above services. A few examples of how you could start up your stack:

- apache2.2, php54, mysql5.7 and pgsql9.3
- nginx-mainline, php70, mariadb10.2  and pgsql9.6
- apache2.4, hhvm, mariadb10.0  and pgsql9.5

Some batteries are also included:

- phpMyAdmin
- Adminer
- auto mass-virtual host

[image: devilbox]

Answer (score 0):

Installing Xampp on Wİndows may be very needed. Because combination of multiple servers and coordinating with them settings is   difficult and complex. But in Ubuntu these servers are magically so coordinated. You can install  [LAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html) too, but as you want install other softwares as like as Mysql Workbench, modifying new softwares with Lampp is time vesting. So you can setup all needed servers on Ubuntu easily and with some simple steps.  [Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) is here.